# How to translate Tabs in community in salesforce

Tags: community, napili, tab, translation, translation-workbench

In order to translate the tabs in community should we add the translation text in workbench translation for setup component of *navigation menu items*?

When I add the translation text for the tabs in French and after switch from English to French I am not able to see( still tabs are in English). Everything will be translated to French except the tabs in the community.

Does anyone faced this issue/have any idea how to solve it?

thanks.

Comment: Could you screenshot what is not translated so assist further?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am facing the same issue. Managed Topics are nicely translated but Navigation Menu Items are not.
Found this known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eim3QAA
I will wait for 24 hours and check again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to translate community custom tabs:

Go to the builder>>target page (page on which you've created new tabs).

click on the globe icon and switch it to desired language (ex: Chinese).

Rename English tab names to Chinese names.

You will see that the details and related tab will only translate on that particular language u have selected
[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. If the tab text isn't updating after making the change, try adding and removing a new tab via "Add" to force the component to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

go to your org-> setup->translation workbench->translate-> choose the language and object you want to translate.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by selecting the "Navigation Menu Item" Setup Component in Translation Workbench. It's very hard to spot but this is the way to go!

Good luck!